# AngularJS Time to load factory

Tags: angularjs

Hi I've create an application angular, I would login user with a call http get to WS Java. I use a view in angular, to pass parameters between views i use a factory.

My code:
I create angular module

```
angular.module('contactMgr',['ngRoute'])
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope){}])

.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
                 function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

            $routeProvider.when('/',{
              controller: 'homePageCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'assets/partials/homePage.html'
            })
            .when('/login',{
              controller: 'loginCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'assets/partials/login.html'
            })
            .when('/loginError',{
              controller: 'loginErrorCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'assets/partials/loginError.html'
            });
}])
```

Then add controller for login that call WS to execute login. If the WS response ID i call method load in a factory to load the user, and finally i redirect to home page

```
.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','UserLogged',
                         function($scope,$http,$location,UserLogged){
   $scope.loginFunction = function(){
      $http({method: 'GET',
             url: 'http://localhost:8080/TaskManagerWS/login/'+$scope.lg_email+':'+$scope.lg_password
      }).then(function success(data,status,xhr){
                $scope.idUser = data.data;
                if($scope.idUser!=0){
                  UserLogged.load($scope.idUser);
                  $location.path("/");
                } 
                else{ $location.path("/loginError"); }
                },
              function error(data,status,xhr){ alert("Error on call function!"); }
            );
   };
}])
```

my factory to load user

```
.factory('UserLogged',['$http',function($http){
  var userLogged;

  return{
  load: function(id){
     $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/TaskManagerWS/user/id='+id
          }).then(function success(data,status,xhr){
                  userLogged = data.data;
                },
                function error(data,status,xhr){
                  window.alert("Error on call function!");
                }
              );
  },
  get: function(){
         return userLogged;
  }
 }
}])
```

And finally my controller for home page

```
.controller('homePageCtrl',['$scope','UserLogged',function($scope,UserLogged){
     $scope.user = UserLogged.get();
}])
```

All call working fine but, when i redirect to home page I don't see the result.

My home page are only tag "h1" with {{user.name}}.

But if i navigation navbar and change view and then i return to home page the title see.

Why this behavior? I would load immediately factory.

I think that angular before load page and then load factory. There is any instruction to load before factory and then page?

I try to put in the var userLogged on factory a static string and then work fine, the title load immediately. Maybe the time problem are in the $http call.

There is any method to reload view after the response of $http service?

Thanks

SOLVED:

Thanks @Matthew Cawley

I change my loginCTRL and add

```
UserLogged.loadCall($scope.idUser).then(function success(data,status,xhr){
                        UserLogged.loadFactory(data.data);
                        $location.path("/");
                      },
                      function error(data,status,xhr){
                        window.alert("Error on call function!");
                      }
                    );
            }
```

and then i change factory to return $http in the method load and finally i add method to loadFactory to load userLogged.

There is a solution that i don't really like, but seems is the only.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or a Plunker of your code please?

Comment: I never used Plunker, but if copy code here you can't use my WS and then if you don't use my WS and use a var the code work fine. Maybe the problem are in load $http call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're redirecting to the home page to soon, i.e. before the `UserLogged` service has finished loading and set it's own`userLogged` variable to the data returned by the `$http` call.

This means that when you call `$scope.user = UserLogged.get();` in your `homePageCtrl` it goes straight to the service's `get` method and returns nothing (because at this point `userLogged` hasn't been set).

Then, moments later (without really noticing it)... the `$http` call completes and the `userLogged` variable becomes set with the results but it's too late.

**Solution 1: Return a promise to use in the controller**

Return the promise created by the `$http` service by adding the `return` keyword:

```
load: function(id){
   return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/TaskManagerWS/user/id='+id
   })
```

and then in your `loginCtrl`, change:

```
UserLogged.load($scope.idUser);
$location.path("/");
```

to:

```
UserLogged.load($scope.idUser)
    .then(function(){
         $location.path("/");
    });
```

This way you'll only get redirected once the `UserLogged.load()` method has carried out it's work.

**Solution 2: Pass a callback function into the service (or factory).**

Create a function in `loginCtrl` that does a redirect:

```
var redirectToHome = function(){
    $location.path("/");
}
```

Then add an extra `callback` parameter to the service's `load()` function, and execute that `callback` function when the promise is resolved in the service (after userLogged has been set):

```
load: function(id, callback) { // <---- Add extra "callback" parameter
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/TaskManagerWS/user/id='+id
    }).then(function success(data,status,xhr){
        userLogged = data.data;
        callback(); // <---- Execute the callback function (whatever it contains)
    },function error(data,status,xhr){
        window.alert("Error on call function!");
    });   
}
```

Then in the `loginCtrl` when you call services `login` function, do so by passing in a reference to the `redirectToHome` function as the callback as follows:

```
UserLogged.load($scope.idUser, redirectToHome); // <--- redirectToHome becomes the callback.
```

Comment: Yes, there any way to bypass  this problem? Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer (several times after typos) *should* work now (famous last words of all developers).

Comment: But i don't want to redirect ever to home page when i call "load" method in factory.

Comment: No, I see what you're trying to do - the `$location.path` part stays in the `loginCtrl` controller (and only fires once), you're just waiting until the data has loaded before doing the redirect. The `return` keyword enables this behavior by returning the promise created by the `$http` service.

Comment: There is another way, by passing in a callbacks, added that to my answer to make it more complete.